# A bash script that can automate git commit message contents

Tags: scripting, git

Normally when I commit a change to a submodule in Git (and if that's the only change), I will provide the result of `git diff <submodule-name>` to the body of the commit message (with `diff.submodule` set to `log` in my git config). So the message would look something like:

```
Updated Core Submodule

Submodule Core eaedd3f..0721763:
  < Fixed ZA-123: Crash in rendering module
  < Merge 'develop' into 'master'
```

I've been trying to write a script that will automate this, to which I can tie to an alias in my git config. To generate the text above, ideally I'd like to run a command such as:

```
$ git submodule-commit Core
```

This would perform the following (roughly):

1. Stage any change to specified submodule (`Core` in this case)
2. Diff the change to the submodule and store that output text for the message generated later
3. Run `git commit` and provide the subject line (`Updated $1 Submodule`, or something of that sort, where `$1` is `Core` in this example).
4. Add the stored diff result from earlier to the commit message as well

I've not had any luck writing a simple script for this. I'm not very experienced with bash / shell scripts. Could anyone help provide an implementation that accomplishes this?

Comment: You could start with the `--oneline` option for `git log`.

Comment: Running `git log --oneline eaedd3f..0721763 | sed 's,^,  < ,'` will give you the submodule commits formatted as above (but with the short commit ID included), given the range of commits to include.

Comment: That's the easy part. How to pipe that into git commit with a prepended subject text plus 2 newlines is what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key bit of syntax you're missing here is:

```
git commit -m "$(printf "Updated $submodule Submodule\n\n" ; git diff $submodule)"
```

The use of the `$()` form of command substitution inside double quotes sends the output of `git diff...` to `git commit` as a commit message with newlines intact.

I used `printf` here instead of `echo` to prepend the subject line since for anything even slightly complex — like dealing with embedded escapes — `echo` is basically [nonportable](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#Limitations-of-Builtins), for historical reasons.

The rest of the script is left as an exercise to the student. :)

Comment: Again  your solution is simple. If that's all I had to do, I wouldn't have posted here to begin with. You've conveniently left out what I feel is the most difficult part to solve: The string concatenation of subject line + 2 line feeds + result of `git diff $submodule`.

Comment: @void.pointer: Added the header line. I didn't know it wasn't part of "git diff" output.

Comment: Wow much better answer! Thanks for editing. Honestly, I wasn't expecting it to be so simple. I thought I would have to do some crazy `awk` stuff and piping.